# Split ASP Classic and ASP.NET into separate App Pools

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

is it possible to run asp.net and asp classic in separate app pools? The asp classic pages are mixed within the same asp.net application and its sub folders. Basically, I have a site and would like to run the asp.net portion in its own app pool and asp classic in a separate app pool. The intent is to run asp.net in a "web garden" configuration; we can not currently do this if asp.net and asp classic are in the same app pool, due to the fact that the classic portions rely on session variables in process.

We have considered rewriting the classic so that they are self contained in one directory, and switching to an SQL-based session storage for classic. We determined it was easier to attempt to split the app pools, as these two options would require a significant time investment. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible afaik, you can only configure the IIS *Application* pool by Application.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  App pools are set on a per-application basis, and applications can only be defined on a per folder/virtual folder basis.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not mix aspx pages and asp pages in one folder just for that reason: each have to be run under their own app pool. Setting for application pool of classic ASP is different then for NET application in so many way that it basically impossible to run on the same pool.

Answer (score 0):

No can't run one app in two different app pools. Your best bet is to separate them like you mentioned, or to rewrite the classic asp part as an mvc application.